# Error while importing items on a scrapy spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get this to work with Scrapy and it is being really frustrating. I can't import the items.py file. I have tried everything, including adding `from__future__ import absolute import` and destroying and recreating the project and spider with different names a couple of times.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import scrapy
from kano.items import KanoItem


class KatscrapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "katscrap"
    allowed_domains = ["kat.cr"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://kat.cr/usearch/category%3Amusic/2/?field=seeders&sorder=desc',
    )


def parse(self, response):

    self.log("link: %s" % response.xpath(
        '//*[@id][starts-with(@id,"torrent")]/td[1]/div[1]/a[4]//@href').extract())
    item['torrent_url'] = response.xpath(
        '//*[@id][starts-with(@id,"torrent")]/td[1]/div[1]/a[4]//@href').extract()
```

But I still get :

```
ImportError: No module named kano.items
```

This seems to be a kind of common error with scrapy, can someone explain why this happens ?

EDIT :

This is my tree structure :

```
├── kano
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── items.py
│   ├── pipelines.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   └── spiders
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── __init__.pyc
│       └── kat.py
└── scrapy.cfg
```

Comment: What is your project's directory structure ?

Comment: I have added the tree to my question

Comment: How are you trying to run the spider ? Is it `scrapy crawl katscrap` or `python kat.py` ?

Comment: when I run the spider with scrapy crawl it works, but how do I know it is properly importing the item class if when I execute it with python it throws error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `scrapy crawl katscrap` while running the spider instead `python kat.py`. This is happening because when you invoke the command `python kat.py` it searches the `kano` module in your current directory instead of the previous directory.